# Configure Global Security missing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am the Jenkins administrator, however, i cannot find configure global security.
I tried updating Jenkins to latest version but to no avail. I searched online for solutions but could not find any.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Jenkins 2.214.3 version failed to find enable security check box and also the title of Configure Global Security has changed, after hours of search came to the following Jenkins documentation. Stop searching for the check box. Hope it helps.

Beginning with Jenkins 2.214 and Jenkins LTS 2.222.1, the "Enable Security" checkbox has been removed. Jenkins own user database is used as the default security realm.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/managing-security/

Answer (score 0):

Click on Jenkins Dashboard->Manage Jenkins->Security. here you should be able to find the security related info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).